Client error: 405 Method Not Allowed Integrating remita with Laravel and livewire
Please i need help, i don't know what i am doing wrong.
Accessing the API works through postman but not working in my laravel application.
//...........
Client error: `POST https://remitademo.net/remita/exapp/api/v1/send/api/echannelsvc/merchant/api/paymentinit` resulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed` response:

{"responseData":"{\"status\":null,\"responseCode\":\"405\",\"responseMsg\":\"Request method \u0027GET\u0027 not supporte (truncated...)
//.................

$client = new Client();
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => "remitaConsumerKey={$merchantId},remitaConsumerToken={$hash}"
        ];

    $body = [
              "serviceTypeId"=>$serviceTypeId,
              "amount"=>$amount,
              "orderId"=>$orderId,
              "payerName"=> Auth::user()->surname.' '.Auth::user()->firstname,
              "payerEmail"=> Auth::user()->email,
              "payerPhone"=>Auth::user()->phone,
              "description"=>"Payment for Septmeber Fees"
            ];
    
    $request = new Request('POST', 'https://remitademo.net/remita/exapp/api/v1/send/api/echannelsvc/merchant/api/paymentinit', $headers, json_encode($body));
    
    $res = $client->sendAsync($request
);


Are you using GuzzleHttp ?Please ensure.

@Subha
Yes, i'am - GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request and GuzzleHttp\Client

I have posted my answer, please check and let me know your feedback.

The issue lies in your sendAsync($request) part .As per the official-docs  of the Remita API the response of the API should be collected as (since it is an asynchronous request).
$res = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();
echo $res->getBody();

Alternatively you can also use this approach as per Guzzle Documentation.
// Send an asynchronous request.
$res= $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});
$res->wait();

N:B :- Also note that the apiHash is SHA-512 encryption of concatenating merchantId + serviceTypeId + orderId + totalAmount + apiKey.
Try this and let me know.
EDIT :-
Try this and let me know.
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://remitademo.net/remita/exapp/api/v1/send/api/echannelsvc/merchant/api/paymentinit', [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'json' => $body
]);


Does not work. If i dd($request) the body is not passed, it seems that is the problem

@Abenslive , I have edited my answer,please check.
